# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de generar un header y body en un archivo wsdl?

Tags: soap

Amigos, estoy construyendo un archivo `wsdl` que lleva un `header` y el `body`, el cual los construyo en el binding del mismo, el problema está cuando genero el request de entrada donde el `header` no se construye con los atributos con los que estoy creando.

```
 <wsdl:message name="NameVersionInfoHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="VersionInfoHeader" element="tns:VersionInfoHeader" />
      </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateVersion">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://comverse-in.com/prepaid/ccws/CreateVersion" style="document"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:NameVersionInfoHeader" part="VersionInfoHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/> 
            <soap:header message="tns:NameVersionInfoHeader" part="VersionInfoHeader" use="literal" />      
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
```

Esta es la manera en la que construyo mi `wsdl`.  El header necesito que se cree con esta estructura.

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <ccws:VersionInfoHeader>     
         <ccws:ProductVersion></ccws:ProductVersion>     
         <ccws:CustomerVersion></ccws:CustomerVersion>
      </ccws:VersionInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Solo genera lo siguiente

```
<soapenv:Header/>
```

Agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Te recomendaría que coloques el código y no una imagen :).

Comment: copia y pega, luego selecciona todo el código y presiona el botón: { } de esta manera tendrás un bonito formato :D saludos y bienvenido a SOes, por cierto revisa: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta e igual por tu sugerencia.